# python excel reading last empty cell

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlrd

I am trying to read till the last empty cell for the specified number of rows.

Here is my code:

```
for j in xrange(0,REPEAT_CONST,1):              
            if r_sheet.cell_type(row+j,0)== xlrd.XL_CELL_EMPTY:
                    break
```

This code only works if the cell has been written something earlier and deleted. but will not work if the cell is never been edited. Not sure how to handle this. 
Could you please help me to do this.
I will be grateful for your support.

Regards,
Pavan

Answer (score 0):

The error you're experiencing suggests the `rowx` or `colx` arguments are out of bounds [for this sheet](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.Sheet-class).

> In the cell access functions, "rowx" is a row index, counting from zero, and "colx" is a column index, counting from zero. Negative values for row/column indexes and slice positions are supported in the expected fashion.

I just found this out (never used XLRD before) but if you query the `r_sheet.nrows` I bet you'll find that the value is less than `row+j`.  It appears that xlrd only *reads* part of the worksheet, essentially the `UsedRange` from Excel.

So you can use some exception handling, either a `try/catch` block or you could do this. Note this should short-circuit on the first part of the boolean expression whenever `row+j` is greater than the [`nrows`](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966#sheet.Sheet.nrows-attribute) attribute of that sheet.

```
if (row+j <= r_sheet.nrows-1) and (r_sheet.cell_value(row+j,0) = ''):
    break
```

Or, perhaps even with your original method:

```
if (row+j <= r_sheet.nrows-1) and (r_sheet.cell_type(row+j,0)== xlrd.XL_CELL_EMPTY):
    break
```

Comment: No its not working. getting below error.

C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages>python xlsread_1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xlsread_1.py", line 243, in <module>
    if r_sheet.cell(row+j,0) is xlrd.empty_cell:
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\xlrd\sheet.py", line 395, in cell
    xfx = self.cell_xf_index(rowx, colx)
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\xlrd\sheet.py", line 421, in cell_xf_index

    xfx = self._cell_xf_indexes[rowx][colx]
IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: This indicates the row or column index is out of range. I haven't changed that part of your code...

Comment: Also, note *both* possible solutions. Did you try each? do the *both* fail at the same error?

Comment: Even for r_sheet.cell(row+j,0).value == '':, I am getting list index out of range. 
if I edit and delete the cells this approach is working. But for empty cell I am getting list index out of range.

My REPEAT_CONST value is 4 and my 4th row is empty.

Comment: What does your original code do?  Does it give the same error?

Comment: Even my original code will throw the same error!!, If I edit and delete it works fine

Comment: The error you're experiencing suggests the `rowx` or `colx` arguments are out of bounds for this sheet object.  What is the value of `row+j` when the error raises?

Comment: Are you trying to find the first empty column in `row`? Or the first empty row in column A?

Comment: "row+j" value is 53 when error occurs. I am trying to exit at when there is empty cell @ column A.

Comment: I don't think this will fix it, but there was some wrong syntax in my second option above, could you also try `if r_sheet.cell_value(row+j,0) = '':`

Comment: @PavanKangokar have you been able to try the revised solution? Does it work for you?